# Ansible uri call with Django JWT token

Tags: django, testing, jenkins, ansible

I would like to call django server with ansible:

I have called:

```
- name: Check status 200
    uri:
      url: https://{{ rest_server }}/api/users/api-token-auth/
      method: POST
      headers:
        Content-Type: "application/json"
      body: '{"username": "username", "password": "password"}'
      return_content: yes

    register: token
```

and I get the token. Now I would like to use this token for the next call, but I can't figure out how this is working....

I try

```
- name: Check that LOGIN returns a status 200
  uri:
    url: https://{{ rest_server }}/api/users/auth/
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Authorization: "JWT {{ token.content[token] }}"
    body: '{"username": "user", "password": "pass"}'
    return_content: yes

  register: webpage
```

but I get error:

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object has no element {u'cookies': {}, u'vary': u'Accept', u'access_control_allow_headers': u'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, X-CSRFToken, Authorization, Access-Bw, Content-Disposition', u'access_control_allow_methods': u'GET, DELETE, POST, PUT, OPTIONS', u'access_control_allow_credentials': u'true', u'content': u'{\"token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcmtvLnphZHJhdmVjQHJlc3VsdC5zaSIsImV4cCI6MTUxNTAxNDE1OSwidXNlcl9pZCI6NCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJtYXJrby56YWRyYXZlY0ByZXN1bHQuc2kifQ.otlXbiuXnDJPiLrEKdMTKBgBMbvIGApBVH_aPI5mSd4\"}', 'failed': False, u'json': {u'token': u'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcmtvLnphZHJhdmVjQHJlc3VsdC5zaSIsImV4cCI6MTUxNTAxNDE1OSwidXNlcl9pZCI6NCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJtYXJrby56YWRyYXZlY0ByZXN1bHQuc2kifQ.otlXbiuXnDJPiLrEKdMTKBgBMbvIGApBVH_aPI5mSd4'},....

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uri` module returns `content` as string.

Use `{{ (token.content | from_json).token }}` or `{{ token.json.token }}`.

Comment: Now I get this error: uresp['location'] = absolute_location(url, uresp['location'])

Answer (score 0):

I guess the OP figured it out by now since the question was asked 6 years ago, but JWT takes the login information using basic authentication, not as JSON payload, so the actual answer to the question is to use:

```yaml
- name: Check that LOGIN returns a status 200
  uri:
    url: https://{{ rest_server }}/api/users/auth/
    method: POST
    user: "user"
    password: "password"
    force_basic_auth: yes
  register: token

- debug:
    msg: "{{ token.json.data.token }}"
```